# Is it possible to reference other secrets in AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I have 2 different secrets repositories in AWS Secrets Manager. Let's call them `secrets-A` and `secrets-B`, which are used by 2 different microservices which we'll call `micro-A` and `micro-B`.

`micro-A` and `micro-B` both need to access a shared secret value, `secret-AB`. Right now I am storing `secret-AB` in both `secrets-A` and `secrets-B`.

This is obviously fraught because what happens if we forget to update `secret-AB` in *both* `secrets-A` and `secrets-B`? `micro-A` and `micro-B` would then be out of sync.

Ideally I would like to have a common secret repo, `secrets-common` that both can pull from, so that perhaps it would look something like:

```
secrets-common: secret-AB="123456"
secrets-A: secret-AB={{secrets-common.secret-AB}}
secrets-B: secret-AB={{secrets-common.secret-AB}}
```

Note that `micro-A` should know nothing about the values in `secrets-B` and `micro-B` should know nothing about the values in `secrets-A`.

I've been searching around but not finding anything on how to do this.

Comment: No it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Secrets Manager does not work in the way you describe. Its pretty straight forward actually. To get a secret, you need the secret name. Each macro service can retrieve the value by referencing the name.

For example, assume  you are using Java to get the value of a specific secret, the call looks like:

```
public static void getValue(SecretsManagerClient secretsClient,String secretName) {

        try {
            GetSecretValueRequest valueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest.builder()
                .secretId(secretName)
                .build();

            GetSecretValueResponse valueResponse = secretsClient.getSecretValue(valueRequest);
            String secret = valueResponse.secretString();
            System.out.println(secret);

        } catch (SecretsManagerException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, so your recommendation would be to just create `secrets-common` and have both `micro-A` and `micro-B` fetch `secret-AB` from that in addition to their other secrets?

Comment: that is a good way to approach this as its really 1-1. 1 name will return 1 secret value.